# Grails generate-controller makes a bad restful controller

Tags: rest, grails

I'm creating a restful api with grails 3.0.9 but if I generate the controller through the command line with: `grails generate-controller [domain]` 
then my application will give an `Grails runtime exception` when I make a call to the api.

If I in the other hand create the controller manually (which extends the `RestfulController`) then there are no problems. I would like to get the controller generated so I can do some checks in save(), delete() and update()

This is the exception that I get:

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

It looks like it is trying to send the result to a view that does not exist, I should not need to create specific views for my rest api since it should only reply with the http status codes and some JSON.

Is this a bug or is the command `generate-controller` not designed for this?

Comment: Is your request asking for a JSON response?

Comment: can you include the generated controller in your question?

Comment: @Neoryder "can you include the generated controller in your question?" - The generated controller will look just like https://github.com/jeffbrown/generatedcontroller/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/demo/PersonController.groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are generating a request that doesn't specify a `format` and doesn't specify an `Accept` header.  If one of those is used to indicate that you want a JSON response, the default generated controller will respect that.

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/generatedcontroller demonstrates that the default generated controller with Grails 3.0.9 seems to work fine without any views.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. It did work without sending an Accept header but not without the format. Is there some way to always choose json format when nothing is specified?

Comment: With `RestfulController` you can specify `responseFormats` and the order that the formats are specified is significant.  The first format listed is the default.  If all you want is the behavior of the default `RestfulController` then you can leave the controller out of the whole thing and just annotation the domain class with `@Resource`.

Comment: @VatanBytyqi "It did work without sending an Accept header but not without the format." - With the default controller from `generate-controller`, you will need to specify either the `Accept` header or the `format`, not both.

Comment: The README displayed at the bottom of https://github.com/jeffbrown/generatedcontroller shows both, one request uses `format` and the other uses an `Accept` header.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question why you want to use `generate-controller`.

Comment: You can use something like `@Resource(uri='/foo', formats=['json', 'xml'])` on your domain class.

Comment: I need to check if a save was successfull then use a service to send something on a websocket.

Comment: @VatanBytyqi I probably wouldn't use `generate-controller`.  I would probably extend `RestfulController` and override the save action.

Comment: Yea, it seems unnecessary to generate the controller but when I used the `RestfulController` I was not able to just check if super.save() was successfull or not, I had to implement the whole save method and it seemed easier to just generate the controller and do the check inside the generated method. Do you have any suggestion how to check it using the existing code in the ResfulController?

Answer (score -1):

What I an recommend is for you to install the templates and customize it so that it would produce a proper Restful controller.

Comment: You do not need to install templates to produce a proper Restful controller.

Comment: Sorry I interpreted it as wanting to generate controllers that extends the RestfulController

Comment: If using the `web-api` profile there is a `create-restful-controller` command which creates a controller based on the template at https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/blob/a56bfde27cd16cf4c59d4d43e14f0d1f697e6c1c/profiles/web-api/templates/artifacts/RestfulController.groovy.